# What is .pre and .post template hook in cscart

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

In cscart, I went through templatename.post.tpl. What is .post or .pre or .override? Since I want to develop an addon, I'm in the need to know about it. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 3):

Those appear to be [template hooks](http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.0.x/addons/hooking/tpl_hooks.html). The difference is in how they modify the output:

- pre: Prepend text to the hook
- post: Appends text to the hook
- override: Changes the original text of the hook